# What's the difference between static and dynamic binding?

Tags: methods, binding

We are learning about methods in class, and I am having trouble especially with the concept of static vs. dynamic.

Wikipedia says this:

> Methods can be bound to a class at compile time (static binding) or to an object at runtime (dynamic binding).

Can anyone describe what they mean here?

Comment: Interpreted languages usually use dynamic binding; compiled ones usually use static binding. Lisp, Scheme, Python, Perl, Ruby, bash, dos scripting are interpreted and use dynamic binding; Java, C, C++ are compiled and use static binding. Does this help? Of course things are harder, as IronPython is compiled down to IL for instance.

Comment: Can you explain more about what exactly you don't understand? What wasn't clear about Wikipedia's articles on [dynamic binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) and [static binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_binding#Binding_time)?

Comment: Well I was moreso wondering what it means to "bind a method to a class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few links with examples:

[Run time binding or compile time binding?](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/run-time-binding-or-compile-time-binding/30)

[Overloading is compile-time binding](http://skeletoncoder.blogspot.com/2006/09/java-tutorials-overloading-is-compile.html)

[METHOD Overload Vs Overriding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/Overload_Vs_Overriding.aspx)

[C#, early and late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484214/c-early-and-late-binding)